# Angular 2 firebase upload .zip and read files in it

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to upload .zip file and read html file from inside of it. Then show it. Something like http://studio.adform.com/projects/ .

Comment: Hi, Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to host a web site on Firebase, have a look at the [documentation for Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/). While it doesn't start with a zip file, it's often even simpler and just a matter of running `firebase deploy` to deploy your website (or update).

Comment: What I want is - user uploads .zip file with .html file in it. After upload he sees that html file in a frame. So I don't think that is the best answer.

Comment: What you want is not a feature of Firebase Hosting. You can either build the feature yourself, [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), or use what I describe, which is possible today out of the box.